# How can I solve jukto(connected) words in Bangla font in Android?

Tags: android, fonts, glyph, android-fonts, indic

Here is my code for [Bangla](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bangla) in Android:

```
package com.exam;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TextDifferentActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf");
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
        tv.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

#### XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/DefaultFontText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:text="Here is some text." />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/CustomFontText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:text="আল্লাহ">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here it shows আ্ললাহ।, but I need to show it as আল্লাহ. How can I solve the problem?
In my phone, [HTC A3333](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Wildfire), it shows the fonts. Is there any other solution to make it correct?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you do complex glyphs (juktoborno) are always shown as broken characters, only solution i found is to use images for them. You can use **SpannableStringBuilder** for this purpose.But using image only for juktoborno is not perfect because image doesn't synchronize perfectly with characters of the font as shown below:
[image]

So you need replace all characters with images which makes the no of images required pretty high. But no of images can be reduced greatly by using **Overlay** technique. This is what I achieved finally:
[image]