# How to convert english characters to ANSII in java android

Tags: java, android, unicode

I have a string like

```
String name= "আমার নাম Reyjohn";
```

[note that "আমার নাম" is a Bengali or SouthAsian language]

I can convert the string from unicode to ANSII by replacing characters from the string and when I show this converted string using a ANSII font in typeface only "আমার নাম" is showing correctly, but the "Reyjohn" is replaced by the other Bengali character. What would be the best way to convert only the asian language and show them perfectly with the exact English word?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "ANSII"? You may be mixed up between "ASCII" and "ANSI" - although ANSI isn't one specific encoding either.

Comment: I found some font named XXX ANSI.ttf , I configured my method to convert the characters to response correctly for this font. But it handles only the south asian characters, if any English character is in the string then that string is also converted by some other asian characters.

Comment: Well *fonts* aren't the same as *encodings*. It's hard to know what you're really trying to achieve here, to be honest. It sounds like you may want to use two different fonts...

Comment: I just want to show the south asian characters and english characters in a same textview in android perfectly as like my example string

Comment: You need to use a font that handles both set of characters. By the sound of it, the one you are using only support south asian characters

Comment: Yes I know, but when I use those fonts It shows the English perfectly but cant render the Asian characters perfectly, the just show in a very clumsy way. Thats why I need to convert those in ANSII.

Answer (score -1):

`What would be the best way to convert only the asian language`

i think you  have to check the unicode of each and every character ... english characters lies b/w 67-127 , Ascii table !

`perfect English word for asian language`

[How can I solve jukto(connected) words in Bangla font in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654400/how-can-i-solve-juktoconnected-words-in-bangla-font-in-android) , Font name is situated inside this code , may be this code can help you .